# Speaker and camera of my MacBook Air aren't working after installing windows

Tags: macos, camera, windows, speakers

Yesterday I installed Windows 8.1 on my MacBook Air on the partition that contained macOS, so the only OS that exists on my laptop is windows. With addition I had also installed BootCamp drivers on it. But there still exists a  problem with the camera, speakers and tilde and ash keys.

When I opened my device manager in windows all the drivers show no error and are fine but they aren't working. Wifi and bluetooth drivers are working but camera and speakers are not.[image: Image of device manager window]

Has anyone tried removing macOS and installing windows on MacBook? If so please do let me know how you corrected these errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried re-installing the drivers?

From Apple official page:
https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1836?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US

Facetime drivers:
https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1831?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US

Hope this helps.

Cheers.

Comment: Yes I reinstalled the drivers many times but still it wasn't working and btw I am not so concerned about the camera all my worries are about the speakers which aren't working. Can you please help me with this problem?